# MongoDB referencing ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I have problem with my web application. In my app, I have two collection: "post" and "category". I want add by referencing category to post. In post collection I have field "MongoDBRef category" and in post controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Post post)
    {
        _category.GetCategory();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            post.Url = post.Title.GenerateSlug();
            post.Author = User.Identity.Name;
            post.Date = DateTime.Now;
            post.Category = new MongoDBRef("Category", CategoryId);
            _postService.Create(post);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

But didn't work. Can anyone help solve this problem?

This is my field in post class:

```
 public MongoDBRef Category { get; set; }
```

And Category class:

```
  public class Category
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

I want to create post with some category, which is reference from category collection, but I don't have any idea to do this...

Comment: Could explain what you expected the structure of the database to be after this code executes? What is `CategoryId` in the code snippet? It's not a local variable.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with `DbRef` either as it just bloats the database documents with unnecessary metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
        post.Category = new MongoDBRef("Category", CategoryId);
```

to

```
        post.Category = new MongoDBRef("Category", _category.CategoryId);
```

Also agree with commentors - you should not use a MongoDBRef here. It is always a category so just put the category ID in a string.

Comment: So the better way is put ID from category collection to post collection without referencing ? I mean,  create the post and choose category from list category  ?

Comment: No we are just saying use "string" instead of "MongoDBRef"

Comment: Can you explain why I should not use a MongoDBRef ?

Comment: MongoDBRef is used if you are referencing another document and it could be in any collection - so you need to store the collection name. In this case, the document you are referencing is always a category, so MongoDBRef is overkill. You can just put the category id.

Comment: @GregEnnis the `CategoryId` field should be of type `ObjectId` rather than `string`.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I understand it, and the last questions, do i need a category collection ?

Comment: Yes I would think you need it because it seems like you are re-using categories in several different places. In your case I would not embed categories in other documents.

Comment: @Zaid yes thank you, unfortunately too late to edit my comment